# AutoScroll in Facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am creating an app in facebook (using php ) in which i have an anchor tag on top of the page. I want is that when anyone clicks on it.. the page is scrolled down to a div on the same page..

Here is an example of a website that has such functionality:

http://www.metro.co.uk/sport/879373-arsene-wenger-i-dont-want-arsenal-players-at-london-olympics-2012#commentsAnchor

When you click on "M Comments" button it will scroll down automatically. Code seems to be

```
<a class="skip-to-comments" href="#commentsAnchor"></a>
```

i have tried this but it is not helping much

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate top-position of the div
2. Subtract an appropriate offset for all the Facebook stuff
3. Use FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, y) to do the actual scrolling.

(This is only necessary because Facebook apps are running inside an IFrame.)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to utilize the `FB.Canvas.scrollTo(x, y)` function in the Facebook JS SDK ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/ ). The following snippet of code should sort you out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.skip-to-comments').click(function() {
        FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, $($(this).attr('href')).position().top);
        return false;
    });
});
```